# SQL - Join Queries

Tags: sql, join, left-join

Here I have two tables as **student_information** and **exmaination_marks**.

**examination_marks** table have 3 columns for three subjects and include their marks.

I want to select the **roll_number** and **name** of the student from the **student_information** table where sum of the three subject's marks in examination_marks table is less than 100.

Both table has roll_number as primary key.

Here is the query I wrote.

```
select
    si.roll_number,
    si.name
from
    student_information as si
    left outer join examination_marks as em on
        si.roll_number = em.roll_number
where
    sum(em.subject_one + em.subject_two + em.subject_three) < 100;
```

But I got an error saying "**ERROR 1111 (HY000) at line 1: Invalid use of group function**"

Can any one help me with this?

Comment: "`examination_marks` table have 3 columns for three subjects and include their marks." - you probably should normalize that table first.

Comment: You shouldn't use `SUM` for this - that's an aggregate-function. Instead just use `+`.

Answer (score 2):

```
sum(em.subject_one + em.subject_two + em.subject_three)< 100
```

this is the problem . Try these

```
Where (SELECT subject_one + subject_two + subject_three FROM examination_marks WHERE em.roll_number = si.roll_number) < 100
```

Answer (score 0):

`SUM` is an "aggregate function" which can only be used inside a query which has a `GROUP BY` clause.

To get the sum of values *within the same row* you need to use the `+` operator. If the columns are `NULL`-able then you'll also need to use `COALESCE` (or `ISNULL`) to prevent `NULL` values invalidating your entire expression.

Like so:

```
SELECT
    si.roll_number,
    si.name,
    COALESCE( em.subject_one, 0 ) + COALESCE( em.subject_two, 0 ) + COALESCE( em.subject_three, 0 ) AS sum_marks
FROM
    student_information AS si
    LEFT OUTER JOIN examination_marks AS em ON
        si.roll_number = em.roll_number
WHERE
    COALESCE( em.subject_one, 0 ) + COALESCE( em.subject_two, 0 ) + COALESCE( em.subject_three, 0 ) < 100;
```

(If you're wondering why the `COALESCE( em.subje...` expression is repeated in the `SELECT` and `WHERE` clauses, that's because SQL is <del>horribly designed by (obscene profanities)</del> is an unnecessarily verbose language).